# JQ Calender not working until second postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Having an issue with a JQuery [calender plugin](https://code.google.com/p/dyndatetime/wiki/Home) where it won't load until there is another postback initiated after the button is clicked to open the edit item template.

The calender control is within an UpdatePanel, ContentTemplate, ListView and within the EditItemTemplate.

Below is some sudo-esq code I've written which demonstrates the structure of my code.

If anyone has any theories or answers as to why Date in the below example isn't loading the calender jQuery until the DDL autopostback is invoked that would be a great help.

Further clarification, which wasn't clear in the original code snippet, there is a command button within SelectedItem which opens up the selected EditItem where the offending calender functionality isn't working until postback. This part of the page isn't loaded at the start I don't think as it's collapsed.

Thank you in advance.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
         $("#Date").dynDateTime({
             showsTime: true,
             ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
             daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",`enter code here`
             align: "BR",
             electric: false,
             singleClick: false,
             displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
             button: ".next()"
         });
         $("#Date2").dynDateTime({
             showsTime: true,
             ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
             daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
             align: "BR",
             electric: false,
             singleClick: false,
             displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
             button: ".next()"
         });
      });
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ListView>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Date"/>
    <asp: DropDownList ID="DDL" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0"> Option 1 </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListView Value="1"> Option 2 </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Date2"/>
    <asp: DropDownList ID="DDL2" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0"> Option 1 </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListView Value="1"> Option 2 </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
</ItemTemplate>
<SelectedItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="btn1" CommandName="OpenEdit"/>
</SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
</Content>
```

Comment: There might be a issue with UpdatePanel, Once you remove it the plugin will work for sure. So you need to re-initialize the calendar plugin.

Comment: Hmmm - correct sir, <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional" > the attributes cause the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, This will resolve the issue. Put below snippet in your Script block:

```
  $(function () {
     $("#Date").dynDateTime({
         showsTime: true,
         ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
         daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",`enter code here`
         align: "BR",
         electric: false,
         singleClick: false,
         displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
         button: ".next()"
     });
     $("#Date2").dynDateTime({
         showsTime: true,
         ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
         daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
         align: "BR",
         electric: false,
         singleClick: false,
         displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
         button: ".next()"
     });
  });

  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

  prm.add_endRequest(function() {
   // re-bind your jQuery events here
   $("#Date").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",`enter code here`
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"
   });
   $("#Date2").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"
    });
  });
```

Above is the resolution with jQuery code with Update panel. They need to be re-initialize after postbacks.

If you find this as solution, mark this as answer. :)